# Pass the signature of a method and invoke it on another object of the same type

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I want to pass a method around and store it. Let's say the method takes one int and returns void. I'd wrap it in Action< int >.

Now, is there a way to invoke that method but not on the object it originated from but a different instance of the same class?

It's kind of hard to be more specific than that but please ask if anything is confusing and I'll try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, is there a way to invoke that method but not on the object it originated from but a different instance of the same class?

EDIT: Okay, ignore my first attempt. I thought you were talking about a different *class*.

It sounds like you should actually be wrapping the method in an `Action<object, int>` (or a more strongly typed version).

Alternatively, you could create a new delegate using:

```
Action<int> newAction = (Action<int>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>),
                                          newTarget,
                                          oldAction.Method);
```

Comment: Well that's very impractical... How come they don't just let me change the Target property? Also, I'm guessing this method is very slow, right?

Comment: @Darwin: Why do you think it's "very impractical"? They don't let you "just change the Target" because it's a method declared on a completely different type. Heck, there's no guarantee that there even *is* such a method. It seems *entirely* reasonable to me. As for whether it's "very slow" - that's all relative. You may well want to cache the results of looking up such a method.

Comment: @Darwin: Hang on, I think I've completely misunderstood the question... editing.

Comment: Thanks! I did a benchmark to compare this method to a regular call on an instance. The difference seems extremely small. Could you take a look at my benchmark to see if I missed something? http://pastebin.com/UuUhtcF6 Outputs ~2100 ~1990

Comment: @Darwin: Seems reasonable to me. The important bit is really whether it's small enough in your *actual* use case, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Type.GetMethod overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1.aspx) which takes parameter types. This allows you to get the exact method with the specified parametere types.